How do you create a file directory where you can change file paths for an Android app?
More specifically, how do you create folders that the user can move saved files in and out of by changing paths in an Android app?
For example, a photo gallery app where you can create folders to put photos in and create subfolders to put in the folders to even better organize the photos.
Do you have to use room or the Android file system API? Is there some other library or API that I've never heard of?
I have no idea where to start.

This question is similar to: Android create folders in Internal Memory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think that question is too old and outdated.
